# Getting values from a textarea and storing them correctly

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JavaScript program to determine what day of the week a given date can fall on. The user types the date in a textbox and then presses submit.

The ways a date can be entered is:

```
Day/Month/Year --> 6/15/95 for June 6th, 1995
                   6/15/1995 for the same date
Day Month Year --> 15 September 2006
Month Day Year --> February 19, 1994
```

I got it to accept the `Day/Month/Year` and `Month Day, Year`, but for some reason I cannot get it to accept it with the day followed by the month. Here is my code so far.

```
var monthArray = ["January", "February", "March",
                  "April", "May", "June", "July",
                  "August", "September", "October",
                  "November", "December"];

var month;
var day;
var year;

var text1 = getElementById("myTextArea").value;      
var text2 = text1.split(/[\s\/,]+/);  //15 Sep 2001 will be ["15", "Sep", "2001"]
                                      //6/13/95 will be ["6", "13", "95"]
                                      //Sep 15, 2001 will be ["Sep", "15", "2001"]

for(var i = 0; i < text2.length; i++)    //Iterate through all elements in text2
{
   for(var j = 0; j < monthArray.length; j++) //Iterate through all elements in monthArray
   {
      if(text2[i].substring(0, 3) == monthArray[j].substring(0, 3))   //See if one of the elements matches a month string.
      {
         month = j + 1;   //Set month equal to the number. For instance, if Sep month = 9
         text2.splice(i, i + 1);  //Remove the month element. Array should contain ["date", "year"] in that order
         day = text2[0];    //Set day equal to the "date" element.
         year = text2[1];   //Set year equal to the "year" element.
      }
   }
}

if(typeof month == "undefined")    //This will happen if month isn't a string. I.e. it is a number like 5/16/54.
{
   month = text2[0];
   day = text2[1];
   year = text2[2];
}

//This is for a specified year range.
if(year >= 50 && year < 100)
{
   year = 1900 + parseInt(year);
}
else if(year <= 49 && year >= 0)
{
   year = 2000 + parseInt(year);
}
```

When I enter something like 6/15/95 or June 15, 1995 it works fine. But for some reason if I try to enter 15 June 1995, it won't work and I have no idea why. Can anyone spot my mistake? I've been messing with this for hours with no avail. Is there an easier way to do this? Any way I can do this with just some regular expressions? I feel like I am making this way harder than I need to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text2.splice(i, i + 1); is causing text2[i] to become undefined on the next loop iteration if there is a month match.  You are then trying to call substring on undefined which is throwing an error.

I'm guessing if there is a month match you will want to break out of the for loop.

Comment: I added in the break statement and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unclear.
Readable is more important.

Split your code into several functions first. Then union them to erase duplicated code.

1. function detectFormat
2. function transferSlashFormat
3. function transferSpaceFormat
4. function transferCommaFormat

Make every function works.
Then union 2-4 function, erase duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Date out of a string like this:

```
var string = "Sep 15, 2001";
var d = new Date(string)
```

it will return a Date Object, which you can then manipulate however you want, 
and it works with all your given examples.

Comment: We are told that Javascript has an extensive Calender package which we are not allowed to use. If Date is in this package I cannot use it.